# Facing problem while nesting XML tags in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create an XML file in Java, I am expecting to get the following output:

```xml
<Row>
  <customer_name> foo </customer_name>
  <address>
     <street_address> 123 Hemming Way </street_address>
     <city> Brandon </city>
  </address>
  <region> Manitoba </region>
</Row>
```

The output I am getting is without the nesting of `<address>` tag like this:

```xml
<Row>
   <customer_name> foo </customer_name>
   <street_address> 123 Hemming Way </street_address>
   <city> Brandon </city>
   <region> Manitoba </region>
</Row>
```

I don't know how to include separate nesting of `<address>` for `street_address` and `city`.
My code is as follows:

```java
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select  customer_name,street_address,city, region  from customers ");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (rs.next()) {
    Element row = doc.createElement("Row");
    results.appendChild(row);
    for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
        Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));
        row.appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, if you only write generic loop for all columns. You need to write more explicit code, so the `street_address` and `city` are nested inside an `address` tag.

I'd suggest you eliminate the column loop, and write specific code for each column.

Helper methods may be a good idea:

```java
static Element addElement(Element parent, String name) {
    Element elem = parent.getOwnerDocument().createElement(name);
    parent.appendChild(elem);
    return elem;
}

static void addElementValue(Element parent, String name, String value) {
    addElement(parent, name).appendChild(parent.getOwnerDocument().createTextNode(value));
}
```

It is now easier to write the logic:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    Element row = addElement(results, "Row");
    addElementValue(row, "customer_name", rs.getString("customer_name"));
    Element address = addElement(row, "address");
    addElementValue(address, "street_address", rs.getString("street_address"));
    addElementValue(address, "city", rs.getString("city"));
    addElementValue(row, "region", rs.getString("region"));
}
```

This also makes it easier for you to name the elements better, if you so choose, e.g.

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    Element row = addElement(results, "Customer");
    addElementValue(row, "Name", rs.getString("customer_name"));
    Element address = addElement(row, "Address");
    addElementValue(address, "Street", rs.getString("street_address"));
    addElementValue(address, "City", rs.getString("city"));
    addElementValue(row, "Region", rs.getString("region"));
}
```

to create the following XML:

```xml
<Customer>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Address>
        <Street>123 Hemming Way</Street>
        <City>Brandon</City>
    </Address>
    <Region>Manitoba</Region>
</Customer>
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I loop this code inside for loop

Comment: @sith Inside what for loop? Look at the code again. It is a *replacement* for the entire `while (rs.next())` loop.

Comment: oh okie there is a for loop inside the while loop.

Comment: @sith Please **read the answer**. I said: *"I'd suggest you **eliminate the column loop**"*. "column loop" == "for loop"

Comment: That's so kind of you.I will check and let you know if it works:)

Comment: Hello,this code is throwing error,it's not allowing me to use the helper method.Looking to solve it in another way

Comment: @sithj *Throwing* what error? --- What does "not *allowing* me to use the helper method" mean? --- "Allowing" sounds like a compilation issue, but "throwing" is a runtime issue, except that doesn't make sense, because if the code didn't compile, it can't be run. Or did you try running the code anyway, and got a runtime error telling you that compilation failed? If so, then what did you expect?

Comment: I mean my whole code is complex,your code changes my entire structure of the code.I am trying to use if loop inside the for  loop .For example,if the column name matches with street address or city then append address.But I don't know the exact syntax of comparing a column name in if loop

Comment: @sithj *"I am trying to use if loop inside the for loop"* First, `if` is a statement, not a loop. Second, I see no attempt at using an `if` statement inside your `for` loop, so cannot address that. I showed you how best to changed the code you did show to generate the XML you want. If that wasn't your question, then perhaps you should write a better question. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)